# Select object from store by id from store NgRx

Tags: angular, ngrx

How can i select an `Building` from my state depending on the `selectedBuildingId` property of my state?

**my store:**

```js
export interface State extends EntityState<Building> {
    selectedBuildingId: string
}
```

Is it possible to have some selector similar to this one but rather than passing it the id, it just takes the one in the store?

```js
export const selectById = (id: string) 
    => createSelector(selectEntities, (buildingsDic) => buildingsDic[id]);
```

My solution was to just fetch the id from the store and then fetch the `Building` with the id, but I feel like this is not good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have a selector for the selectedBuildingId called `selectBuildingId`, you can use a selector inside an other selector.

```
export const selectById = createSelector(selectEntities, selectBuildingId, (buildingsDic, id) => buildingsDic[id]);
```

Take a look at the [NGRX doc](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-for-multiple-pieces-of-state)

Comment: Ohhh, i always thought i could only use one "inside-selector" in the `createSelector`. Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: @Deitsch keep in mind that the selector is going to fire everytime any of the used selector changes

Comment: Will do, this is the exact behavior i am looking for!